# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function Why my object is not converting to array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function Why my object is not converting to array? this is the error that I am facing I am trying to map all the item which is currently object but I want to convert it to array to map all them how can I do that? its not been converted into array I tried some solutions on internet how can I do that?

Currenlty its giving me null and when i first const propertyValues = Object.values(item); it gave me  ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function error

```
const renderImages = ({ item, index }) => {
        console.log(item)
        if (!item || !Array.isArray(item)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        const propertyValues = Object.values(item);
        console.log(propertyValues);
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.images}>
                {item.map((url) => (
                    <Image key={url} style={styles.pic} source={{ uri: url }} />
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    };
```

If i do nothing just log the item it logs something like this:

```
 LOG  {"picture": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myprojectfirebase.appspot.com/o/file%3A%2Fdata%2Fuser%2F0%2Fhost.exp.exponent%2Fcache%2FExperienceData%2F%252540anonymous%25252FYounme-4dc528f7-0647-403c-9671-6a595b71bf0b%2FImagePicker%2Fba5eb500-c4e3-4199-9cef-5a8bfb3b1219.jpeg?alt=media&token=49041038-deef-40d9-9809-41210982ae36"}



       {
                    userdata ?
                        <FlashList
                            data={userdata.pictures}
                            renderItem={renderImages}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                            getItemCount={() => userdata.pictures.length}
                            getItem={(data, index) => data[index]}
                            initialNumToRender={5}
                            windowSize={5}
                            ListHeaderComponent={
                                   ...//
    
    }

}
    
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

If `item` is an object, this code will always return `null`:

```
if (!item || !Array.isArray(item)) {
  return null;
}
```

Additionally, if you want to create an array of URLs,  you can simply use `Object.keys` and `.map` to create an array of `item` urls.

```
const properties = Object.keys(item);
const values = properties.map((p) => item[p].url);
```

Since `item` just has one `picture`, why not simplify:

```
const renderImages = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.images}>
      <Image key={item.picture} style={styles.pic} source={{ uri: item.picture }} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: yep but i want to change it to an array to map how to do that?

Comment: If `item` looks like `{'picture':'url...'}` - what are you trying to map it into? `[url..., url...]`? There isn't enough information. Does each item just contain one picture?

Comment: yes one item only contain one picture url

Comment: If your item has one image, why are you creating `images` and trying to iterate over `images.map`? Just use `<Image key={item.picture} style={styles.pic} source={{ uri: item.picture }} />` and drop the map and if checks.

Comment: i mean there are many item but all item contains only one image

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing:

```js
const renderImages = ({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.images}>
      <Image key={url.picture} style={styles.pic} source={{ uri: url.picture }} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: the typeof object is still  LOG  object

Comment: Can you share from where the item come from?

Comment: Looks like the problem is from the item object before it renders in your `renderImage`

Comment: item is coming from userdata that i am fetching api

Comment: Can you `console.log(typeof item)`

Comment: LOG  object
 LOG  object
 LOG  object
 LOG  object
 LOG  object
 LOG  object
 LOG  object

Comment: hey sorry for late response i want to first map all the pictures before displaying that's the issue